# Custom manager - querying on abstract base class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've written an abstract base class which groups together common fields for some of my tables.  I would like to be able to query all of those fields in the same way, using a manager.

```
class TemporalModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    today = TodayManager()

    time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        get_latest_by = 'time'
```

One simple example of this, as shown above, is to be able to query subclasses of TemporalModel (which all have a 'time' field) for the entries today.

I thus wrote a manager:

```
class TodayManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        today = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, tzinfo=now.tzinfo)
        tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)

        qs = models.Manager.get_query_set(self).filter(time >= today)
        qs = qs.filter(time < tomorrow)

        return qs
```

Attempting to use this fails with a NameError (time not defined).  I presume that this is for the same reason as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549898/django-custom-model-manager-queries-in-abstract-classes) - the field is not on the abstract class, but rather on the subclass.

However, I'm never actually calling this on the abstract class.  If I have something like the following:

```
class SomeTemporalThing(TemporalModel):
    pass # I'm a real table! :)
```

then I want to be able to call, eg, SomeTemporalThing.today.all(), and have django perform the time >= today / time < tomorrow lookups on the child table.

Is it possible to achieve this without moving the manager definition to the child class (which would result in repetition)?

My reading of the [custom manager documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance) suggests that it should be possible, but I'm stumped as to how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing should be possible.  The error you are seeing is not related to inheritance of the `Manager` objects, but rather an incorrect specification to the `filter()` function of the `QuerySet`.

Instead of

```
qs = models.Manager.get_query_set(self).filter(time >= today)
```

it should be

```
qs = models.Manager.get_query_set(self).filter(time_gte=today)
```

The same applies to your `time < tomorrow` filter parameter.

See [QuerySet API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte).

Comment: This is the part where I accept both your answer and the fact that I'm an idiot.  Cheers mate :)